# Prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+e}<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Of course, you can use the following formula

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} = \frac{\pi\coth(\pi a)}{2a} - \frac{1}{2a^2},$$

but which is too "advanced". We want to find a solution only depending on inequality estimation only.

Maybe, we can obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+e}&\le \sum_{n=2}^{100}\frac{1}{n^2+e}+\sum_{101}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=2}^{100}\left(\frac{1}{n^2+e}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1+\sum_{n=2}^{100}\left(\frac{1}{n^2+e}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)<\frac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
which is true by checking on machine, but too hard to compute by hand.

Comment: That looks quite hard, since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2+e}\approx0.499915$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, it's sharp.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n^2+e}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{e^k}{n^{2k+2}}$$

So your sum is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-e)^{k-1}(\zeta(2k)-1)$$ Not sure if that helps. Certainly, it is an alternating sequence, so when it is decreasing in absolute value (always?) you can get an upper bound of with the sum of any odd number of terms, which is easier than finding an upper bound for a positive sum.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives the upper bound for this alternating sum $<0.5$ with $21$ terms, so a direct non-computational argument is gonna be hard.

Comment: May I ask... what would be the purpose of using "elementary" methods to find an upper bound when you have an exact formula?

Comment: Well, given how close this sum is to $1/2,$ such a proof might have an implicit explanation for why the sum is so close to $1/2.$ @Momo But read "A Mathematicians Apology" if you need to understand that not all math requires a purpose.  $e^{\pi\sqrt {163}}$ is remarkably close to an integer, and the reasons for this takes you into a deep dive into quadratic fields over the rationals, and unique factorization of the integers there.

Comment: Is this just something you're interested in or is it an exercise you've seen?

Answer (score 8):

I only use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}$ for $k=2,4,6$.

Using $\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2+e} = \frac{e}{n^2(n^2+e)}$, it suffices to show that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n^2+e)} > \frac{\pi^2-9}{9e}$. Then using $\frac{1}{n^4}-\frac{1}{n^2(n^2+e)} = \frac{e}{n^4(n^2+e)}$, it suffices to show $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4(n^2+e)} < \frac{\pi^4-90}{90e}-\frac{\pi^2-9}{9e^2}$. Equivalently, we wish to show $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4(n^2+e)} < \frac{\pi^4-90}{90e}-\frac{\pi^2-9}{9e^2}-\frac{1}{16(4+e)}$. So it suffices to show $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6} < \frac{\pi^4-90}{90e}-\frac{\pi^2-9}{9e^2}-\frac{1}{16(4+e)}$, which is equivalent to $\frac{\pi^6}{945}-\frac{65}{64} < \frac{\pi^4-90}{90e}-\frac{\pi^2-9}{9e^2}-\frac{1}{16(4+e)}$, which is easy to do by hand/calculator (there's actually some room to spare).

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment (I haven't enough reputation to comment).
Exact sum result:
$${{i\,\left(\psi_{0}(2-\sqrt{e}\,i)+\gamma\right)}\over{2\,\sqrt{e}
}}-{{i\,\left(\psi_{0}(\sqrt{e}\,i+2)+\gamma\right)}\over{2\,\sqrt{e
}}}$$
or
$$\frac{-3 e-1+(1+e) \pi  \sqrt{e} \coth \left(\sqrt{e} \pi \right)}{2 e (1+e)}$$